# Spring Batch always starts with Spring Boot: spring.batch.job.enabled=false DOES NOT work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Boot Application called MyApplication.
I also have a Spring Batch Application called JobStartupRunner.
Whenever I start up MyApplication as a Spring Boot Application, JobStartupRunner also runs.  I DO have spring.batch.job.enabled=false in the application.properties file and it doesn't work.

Here is the code:
...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = RepositoryImpl.class)
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

}
```

...

Here is the Spring Batch app:
...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JobStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobStartupRunner.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        Long jobId = null;
        try {
          jobId = jobLauncher.launchJob(jobParameters);
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobRestartException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Ran with JOB ID: " + jobId);
   }
}
```

...
Here is the Spring Batch Config class:
...

```
@Configuration("jobConfig")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mystuff")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig extends AbstractJobConfig {
 <more stuff here>
}
```

...

How can I prevent the Spring Batch app from starting when the "master" application starts.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have two `@SpringBootApplication` in one project? If yes then this may be the root cause of the strange behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spring.batch.job.enabled` only affects the `Job` that are declared as the spring beans.

But the job starts now because you manually start it by implementing a `CommandLineRunner` rather than declare them as `Job` bean , so `spring.batch.job.enabled` does not have effect on them.

You can simply exclude `JobStartupRunner` in the component scan such that it will not execute anymore :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={ @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=JobStartupRunner.class)})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm glad the solution was something simple and sensible.

Comment: @GothsterC . Glad to hear . So consider to accept or vote up my answer ? 